# Lower bound of confidence interval

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

Given 10 nail lengths with

$$\bar{x} = 59.98 \quad,\quad\sigma = 0.26$$

Q: What is the shortest average nail length on basis of the sample probe? You can freely choose the level of significance.

---

I guess they want the lower bound of the confidence intervall.

I found out that the lower bound is described as

$$\bar{x}-z\cdot\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Lets say $\alpha = 5\%$

How do I calculate the z-score without having a $\mu$?

Comment: Shortest average nail length doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: I swear to god i know. But its literally how my professor has formulated it. "How big is the average nail length at least?"

Comment: You could be cheeky and say $\[0,\infty)$ with significance level $0%$ — this question is just bad

Comment: Is the comma in $59, 98$ a decimal separator? You should either say so, or use a dot instead of a comma; commas are not used as decimal separators in English.

Comment: In germany we use the comma sign as a decimal seperator, forgot to change it.